# Changing Windows listed Internet Time Server with a command line script

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

It's been a long time since I last came here on another account. I'm currently dealing with a client's machines with strict security protocols that mean they cannot access the time.windows.com server from their internet date and time settings. Every time daylight savings starts or finishes, their machines borderline brick themselves country wide because of the programs they run.

The affected machines all run Windows 7 Professional. We've run the latest Windows security patch KB3162835 which affects this, but that alone hasn't had any effect.

So we need an alternative time sync server. We've settled on pool.ntp.org

I have 350+ machines to do this on, so I've tried to create an auto-run script I can deploy but it's not having an effect. What it needs to do from the command line is change time.windows.com to pool.ntp.org and then hit the "update now" button next to it.

The listing we're trying to change is found under:

Control Panel > Date and Time > Internet Time Tab > Change Settings > Server + Update Now.

I've been using these sites: 
https://ss64.com/nt/net-time.html and 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490716.aspx

To try and formulate a command to run, and I've ended up with this:
 `W32TM.exe /config /manualpeerlist:"time.nist.gov pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:manual /update`

However, this is not changing the listed server to synchronise with, it's still remaining on time.windows.com

Can anyone offer me a suggestion for fixing up this command line script?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Time AND NTP time are two different ways of updating time in windows.  The former is configured using the Date/Time control panel, the latter is W32TM.

Found an article about "Internet Time Server" (I needed to update some too) https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/135522-add-remove-internet-time-servers-windows.html.

TL;DR for commandline query use -

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers
```

to add another server (in the same way the UI does) -

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers /v 0 /t REG_SZ /d Your.Server.Here
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers  /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
```